Combine LeftPad and Truncate in String.format()
TLDR; 1 String.format(XXX, YYY) or "No this is not supported".
Add if the number is to short leading zero. If the number is to long (longer than 6) cut it.
long number1 = 123456789L;
long number2 = 123L;

String result1 = String.format(?, number1);
String result2 = String.format(?, number2);

Expected:
result1 is 123456
result2 is 000123
Adding leading zeros can be done with:
String.format("%06d",value)
Cutting the string can be done with:
String.format("%6.6s", value)
But how do I combine both?

javadoc  -- basically, AFAIK, you can't do both with one format, but maybe String.format("%6.6s", String.format("%06d", value)) or similar (you can also use plain substring to limit the size)

@user85421 this is not the answer I am looking for. I could also use .subString(0,6) or create a method like @Federico, unshift the array etc.

then, what answer are you looking for? "But how do I combine both?" -> as I suggested above: "String.format("%6.6s", String.format("%06d", value))"

@Pwnstar The Javadocs are right there. Seems like “the answer you’re looking for” is in them.

@user85421 what you did was not "combining" but "chaining" them together.
A combination would be something like String.format("%06.6d", value)

yes, but as the documentation shows, that is not allowed: "For character, integral, and date/time argument types and the percent and line separator conversions, the precision is not applicable; if a precision is provided, an exception will be thrown." (emp;hasis added)

Meaning the answer to my question is "It does not work using solely String.format".

You can combine both of them by creating a seperate method and pass whatever number you need to format to it :
public static String formattingNumber(long inputNumber) {
    String str = String.valueOf(inputNumber);
    if (str.length() > 6) {
        return str.substring(0, 6); // if length is more than 6 perform truncate operation
    } else {
        return String.format("%06d", inputNumber); // if length is less than 6 left padding zero
    }
}

You can call above method from your your main method and print them out like below
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long number1 = 123456789L;
    long number2 = 123L;

    String result1 = formattingNumber(number1);
    String result2 = formattingNumber(number2);

    System.out.println(result1);
    System.out.println(result2);

}


You didn't read the question. I want 1 String.format if possible.
